# How can I switch git branches when there is an untracked file error?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-flow

Using SourceTree when I try to switch back to master from a feature branch I created I get an error:

```
Updating the following directories would lose untracked files in it
```

I want to switch back to master to make another feature branch but am unable to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually figured this out myself. By using the terminal in SourceTree, I entered the following command:

```
git checkout -f master
```

The -f flag forces it to switch even if there is an error. It still showed the error before switching but it did switch and I was able to make a new feature branch.

Comment: Were there any repercussions when switching with untracked files?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your file is added to the index

```
git add <filename>
```

Then:

---

Commit your changes

```
git commit
```

---

Or stash them

```
git stash
```

You can access the stashed changes later by this:

```
git stash pop
```